# SHOP_CURRENCY_LOCALE = 'en_US.UTF-8'

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I am trying to include the line

```
SHOP_CURRENCY_LOCALE = 'en_US.UTF-8'
```

inside my settings.py file but it's giving me the following error:-

```
raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg % currency_locale)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Invalid currency locale specified f
or SHOP_CURRENCY_LOCALE: 'en_US.UTF-8'. You'll need to set the locale for your s
ystem, or configure the SHOP_CURRENCY_LOCALE setting in your settings module.
```

Comment: The locale you want must be installed on your computer. If you are using Linux or Mac you can check by executing "locale -a".

Comment: I am using windows can you tell me how to install or configure it on windows

Comment: I don't think UTF-8 suffix is available on Windows. Try en_US, en-us or just us. [Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39cwe7zf(v=vs.140).aspx)

Comment: Yes it worked for SHOP_CURRENCY_LOCALE = 'us'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The locale must be installed on your computer. On Linux or Mac you can get the installed locales by executing "locale -a".

Windows is a bit wierder and I don't think UTF-8 suffix is available. Here is a list of Windows locales. You should use the language string.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39cwe7zf(v=vs.140).aspx

In your case that would be 'us'.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question doesn't specify an operating system, I thought I'd add that in Debian, this issue can be fixed as follows:

```
apt-get install -y locales
sed -i -e 's/# en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```